# ListView with Strings and Images

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I want the ListView to display a String then Image and String again one the same line but it is showing the same String to the left and right of the Image how can I fix this. I am still learning java and can't figure it out.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String color_names[] = {"red", "green", "blue", "yellow", "pink", "brown"};
Integer image_id[] = {R.drawable.red, R.drawable.green, R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.yellow, R.drawable.pink, R.drawable.brown};
String number_list[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Customlistadapter adapter = new Customlistadapter(this, image_id, color_names, number_list);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

Customlistadapter

```
public class Customlistadapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    String[] color_names;
    String[] number_list;
    Integer[] image_id;
    Context context;
public Customlistadapter(Activity context, Integer[] image_id, String[] color_names, String[] text){
    super(context, R.layout.list_row, text);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.color_names = text;
    this.image_id = image_id;
    this.number_list = text;
    this.context = context;
    }
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View single_row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null,
    true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) single_row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) single_row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) single_row.findViewById(R.id.textList);
    textView.setText(color_names[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(image_id[position]);
    textView1.setText(number_list[position]);
    return single_row;
      }
    }
```

list_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TextView1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
public Customlistadapter(Activity context, Integer[] image_id, String[] color_names, String[] text){
    super(context, R.layout.list_row, text);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.color_names = text;
    this.image_id = image_id;
    this.number_list = text;
    this.context = context;
    }
```

you should have `this.color_names = color_names;` instead of `this.color_names = text;`

Basically, your string arrays contain the same values, that is why you have the same string next to the image.

You should also have a look at the view holder pattern and how to use the convertView http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

And you should look into the java naming conventions. You should use camelcase. For example Customlistadapter -> CustomListAdapter, color_names -> colorNames, etc ...